# Java 1.6 SDK on Mac OS 10.5

Tags: java, macos

Has Java 1.6 SDK been released for mac? I can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, but only for 64-bit Intel-based Macs, i.e. Macs using Core 2 (duo or solo) or Xeon chips. The original Core chip is not supported, nor is any PPC chip. Also, Java 6 is currently Leopard-only. The update should appear in Software Update, if you have a compatible Mac and recent-enough OS version.

Here are the release notes for the [first update](http://developer.apple.com/releasenotes/Java/JavaLeopardUpdate1RN/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html). And here are the [second update](http://developer.apple.com/releasenotes/Java/JavaLeopardUpdate2RN/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html)'s release notes.

Comment: No, I don't have any "insider" information. Sooner would be better than later IMHO though - the PSU on my Intel machine is blown, so I'm stuck using my old G4 for the time being. :-(

Comment: Actually, my Macbook has an Intel Core 2 Duo processor, Intel's website shows that it is 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, Core 2 chips (both solo and duo) are 64-bit. So are the Xeons used in the Mac Pro. The original Core (not 2) that was used in 1st-gen MacIntels is 32-bit.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have a 64-bit Intel-based Mac you may also be interested in [SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) which is an independent X11-based port of Java 1.6 based on the FreeBSD version.

Comment: That would be the FreeBSD version. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple released 1.6_07 about a month ago. Look for 1.6_10 around about 2010, given how long it took them to get 07 out. And as already stated, it's only for 64bit Macs.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont see it, you may have to go to the [Developers Connection for apple](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/Java/).  If you want to download Java, you may have to signup for a free account.

Answer (score 0):

As msanders said, SoyLatte might be good in a pinch, but be aware that the latest version of SoyLatte, 1.0.3, is Java 1.6.0_03. The most recent version from Sun is 1.6_10. That may not matter for what you're doing, but you should keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a version of the OpenJDK 1.7 [here](http://www.intricatesoftware.com/OpenJDK/macppc/openjdk7u2-macppc-fcs-2012-03-14.tar.bz2)

I'm running it on 10.5.8, on a PPC ("cheese grater",) with Eclipse 4.3.2 / Kepler, and it all seems to work fine.  :-)
(though, in honesty, a new configuration on the box, so we'll see how it goes over time)